# RSpec 3 - Test controller action that does not have routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller, rspec3

I have a controller and there is an action within that controller.  That action contains only a few lines of code and this method doesn't have any routes, as follows:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
   def action_a # an action does have routes
      ..some code..
   end

   def action b #(an action without a route, just contains few logic)
      ..some code..
   end
end
```

My question is what is a proper way to write rspec to test `action_b` ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem or question?

Comment: Where does `action_b` get called from?

Comment: @AndyWaite, `action_b` is called from another action within the same controller and not by any browser request.

Comment: @AndyWaite, i edited my question. i want to know the syntax for writing rspec for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action_b` should really be a private method. Normally, you would not test this directly, you would verify it implicitly by testing `action_a`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping out. but let me know if it is possible to write such rspec like scenario of my question ? actually, i googled a lot but couldn't find any useful reference

Comment: I don't understand, there's nothing special about it. Test it as you would any other public method in a class.

Comment: Andy Waite - Done. converting it into private method.